# AWS EC2 instance Login failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, authentication

I am getting below error when trying to login into my AWS EC2 instance. Last login was around 2 weeks back and everything was working fine so the password I am using is correct. No other information is available on the error message.

Is there a way I can see any logs through management console ?

Appreciate any help on this.

---

### Remote Desktop Connection

An authentication error has occurred.The function requested is not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue. Below is response from AWS technical support team:
Looking at the error message you posted, this is due to a recent patch (KB4103727) that Microsoft has released to fix a vulnerability. It is a mandatory requirement from Microsoft that both the client machine (the computer from which you are trying to RDP into your instances) and the remote server (your EC2 instance) has the latest updates installed. If one of these machines has the latest updates installed and the other does not, RDP connection would fail.

Note: If you see your Windows is up to date and you do not see the KB4103727 installed, it could be a different KB article which applied the KB4103727 as a cumulative update. If this is the case, please uninstall all KBs that were installed recently before the RDP connection was broken.

For more information about this hotfix, please refer to the Microsoft documentation below:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/yongrhee/2018/05/09/after-may-2018-security-update-rdp-an-authentication-error-occurred-this-could-be-due-to-credssp-encryption-oracle-remediation/
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093492/credssp-updates-for-cve-2018-0886-march-13-2018

There are multiple workarounds for this issue:

Option 1: If the update is installed on your client (workstation) and is not installed on your EC2 instance.

Uninstall KB4103727 from your client machine.  After you uninstall the KB and gain RDP access to the EC2 instance, you can patch the instance with latest updates first and then update your client machine with the KB by running Windows Update again.

Alternately, you can keep your client machine updated and you can install latest Windows updates on your EC2 instance remotely using SSM Run Command. For detailed instructions on how to configure your instance to use SSM Run Command, please refer to the below documentation:

SSM Prerequisites: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-prereqs.html
Run Command Tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/tutorial_run_command.html#rc-tutorial-ui

After you configure your instance to use SSM Run Command, you can execute the Run Command document "AWS-InstallWindowsUpdates" remotely on your instance.

Option 2: If the KB is installed on your EC2 instance and is not installed on your client machine

Run Windows Update on your client machine and install latest software updates. Once the latest updates are installed on both your instance and the client machine, you should be able to RDP into the instance.

Alternately, if you have a backup AMI or an EBS snapshot created before the patch was installed on your EC2 instance, you may consider restoring your instance from the backup to roll back the installed software updates.

Option 3: There is a workaround suggested by third party websites to disable the check altogether on the unpatched Windows machine and RDP should work normally. On the unpatched machine, open a command prompt with Administrator privileges and run the command mentioned below:

reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters" /f /v AllowEncryptionOracle /t REG_DWORD /d 2

Please note, you may have to reboot your Windows machine for the changes to take effect after you install/uninstall the KB.

*So, finally I had to uninstall mentioned update from client machine(using which I was trying to connect to the aws instance) which allowed me to connect to the instance. Once connect, I updated the instance with windows updates and rebooted it which resolved the issue.*

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are facing [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46e1cd52-52b3-4427-88a3-200f87319e23/remote-desktop-authentication-error-has-occurred-the-function-requested-is-not-supported?forum=w7itpronetworking) issue.

Bottemline, This is caused by a Microsoft Security Patch. The Microsoft Security patch issued on Tuesday, May 8th 2018 triggered the problem by setting and requiring remote connections at the highest level.

Simply adjust the Remote Desktop settings on the host machine to a lower security level. From File Explorer, choose Computer, right-click and select Properties, then click Change Settings, and go to the Remote tab.

From Windows 10, uncheck the option to “Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication (recommended)”

From Windows 7, it’s setting the option to the Less Secure option rather than More Secure

Once these are set, users can remote to the machine again.

If you don't have any other way into the machine except Remote Desktop, I'm afraid the machine is lost.

Comment: You are right, it is due to security patch. Machine is not lost as there is a work around for this issue.